# PyQt designer adding slot ask me for ui_form.h

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, signals-slots

I just started with QtCreator and create a python project with a window now I am try to add a slot with the signal "clicked" on the gui and it ask me for .h file but as I am coding in python I don't undestand why it ask me for a C file.

I see that I can write the event myself in the file ui_form.py but once I use "pyside6-uic form.ui -o ui_form.py" it disappear like I have to design the interface and once itś done write the events and don´t run pyside6-uic again. Once I write the events I can't modify the window and its widgets. Is that the normal behavior of the tool ?

Comment: Adding slots and signals in Designer/Creator only makes sense if you want to directly connect them in the UI, but it doesn't do anything special: it just adds the code for that connection. Also, custom signals/slots can only be created for the top window or for promoted widgets, and you need to implement them on the python side anyway. This custom signal/slot feature is something that may ease up things in very complex UIs: unless you are in this whole situation, and considering that slots are usually not required in Python, you should really not need to do it: just do it by code.

Comment: Besides, you're not expected to edit pyuic created files. **Never**. Please read how to properly [use Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) with pyuic.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me out this , somehow the auto-completion feature was not working and that was not helping , I wasn't saving the form I think it was that. Now I can write the events without touching the pyuic files.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your comment above. Note that IDEs are not always capable of providing proper completion for dynamically created attributes (which is what pyuic objects do). Also, be careful with terminology: an *event* is an abstract representation of something that's normally triggered by the OS (mouse movements, key presses, timers, system calls, etc.). Slots are certainly *not* events (they are a *possible* and indirect target of events), and neither are signals (which can only be emitted as a consequence of an event). I sincerely doubt that you're "writing events".